# unable to open blender

Tags: error

I have just installed blender and i'm trying to open it, but it pops up a message box saying "Limited Platform Support", when i click continue anyway button, it just shows grey screen and crashes, when run from terminal i got this error message:

```
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties
'
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x000000014192DE4C
Module  : C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\blender.exe
```

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information for as to give a good answer. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn how you could help us to give good answers.